# Creating a wireless remote

Tags: bluetooth, remote-control

I am trying to create a wireless remote control to control a servo motor via Bluetooth. What all do I need to establish this? I did some research and found the following:

[Tinyduino](https://tiny-circuits.com/products/tinyduino/)

[Bluetooth low energy shield](https://tiny-circuits.com/shop/tinyshield-bluetooth-le/)

Would these be enough (in addition to the servo motor) to establish my needs? Any advice on how I would go about coding this? I can research on the specifics but hints on functions to use would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I need to be able to control the system wirelessly (may it be Bluetooth or whatever) through a remote control. This remote control could be a push button system or an app on the phone. I do not have this designed yet. I do not know how to make iPhone apps so the best solution for me would be a simple push button on/off switch that can wirelessly tell the servo motor to either turn 90º clockwise or counterclockwise.

The RFDuino suggestion is very helpful, thank you for that. Can anyone recommend a push-button switch (small) that can wirelessly transmit the signal to the servo motor on the device? I hope this clears things up. Thanks!

Comment: You're a little vague here. You want to create the "remote control", or make your project "remote controllable" (I'm assuming thru your phone?)? Do you have the app/program for your phone already or are you yet to develop it? Or are you controlling via Bluetooth on another arduino?

Comment: As Madivad points out it's unclear what you're trying to do. Add some more details about the project and we can help you better.

Comment: @Madivad - thanks for the comment. I added more detail to my post. I need to make the project remote controllable and need to make a remote control for it. I cannot use an app since I do not know how to program iOS (though it would easiest to do this way if I could). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would also check out [RFDuino](http://www.rfduino.com/).

Basically it's a finger-tip sized, Arduino compatible, wireless enabled microcontroller, low cost enough to leave in all of your projects.

The RFduino runs Arduino code and can do everything an Arduino can.